# Encountering 401 error when using node-couchdb module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I'm trying to connect to a CouchDB server in my Node.js application using the node-couchdb module, but I'm running into an issue.

Here's the code I'm using to connect to CouchDB:

```
javascript
const NodeCouchDb = require("node-couchdb");

const couch = new NodeCouchDb({
  auth: {
    user: "my-username",
    password: "my-password",
  },
});

couch.listDatabases().then(function (dbs) {
  console.log(dbs);
});
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error message:

```
RequestError: Unexpected status code while fetching documents from the database: 401
```

I've confirmed that my CouchDB username and password are correct, and I can log in to the CouchDB admin interface without any problems. I've also confirmed that my CouchDB server is running and responding to HTTP requests as expected.

I'm using CouchDB version 3.3.2, Node.js version 18.15.0, and node-couchdb module version 2.0.0.

For additional context, I've also uploaded the code to my GitHub repository. You can view it [here](https://github.com/eliajhmauve/couchcustomers.git). Any help in diagnosing this issue would be greatly appreciated!

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!

I tried to connect to my CouchDB server using the node-couchdb module in my Node.js application. I expected the couch.listDatabases() function to return a list of all databases in my CouchDB server, which I would then log to the console. However, when I run my code, I get a RequestError: Unexpected status code while fetching documents from the database: 401 error instead. Despite confirming that my CouchDB username and password are correct and that my CouchDB server is running and responding to HTTP requests as expected, I'm still encountering this issue.